# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens...but it does?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I´ve been fighting with this problem for the past hour and am about to jump out of the window. I´m trying to do an update query with a variable number of arguments: The data will come through a form but some fields (surName2 and email) are optional, so they will only be included in the query if the user fills them with data.

So I check if they're set and if so modify the query through the string **$strFields**, then add them to the $pdo query with **bindValue()**. However when I run this I get an error message saying that the number of bound parameters doesn't match those in the query. I just can't find what I'm doing wrong, all 6 variables have data and all binds are being executed but it just won't work:

```
$strFields = '';
            if (isset($_POST['surName2'])) $strFields .= ', surName2=:surName2';
            if (isset($_POST['email'])) $strFields .= ', email=:email';

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET userName=:userName, name=:name, surName1:=surName1'.$strFields.' WHERE user_id=:user_id');
            $stmt->bindValue(':userName', $_POST['userName']);
            $stmt->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name']);
            $stmt->bindValue(':surName1', $_POST['surName1']);
            if (isset($_POST['surName2'])) $stmt->bindValue(':surName2', $_POST['surName2']);
            if (isset($_POST['email'])) $stmt->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
            $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $_POST['user_id']);

            $stmt->execute();//Throws the error
```

Comment: Output query text and see what is wrong.

Comment: There is a typo **surname1:=surName1** — the colon should be after the equal character

Comment: just don't use named placeholders. they are so much confusion

Comment: @YourCommonSense aren't placeholders a good practice to protect against SQL injection?

Comment: I said *named* placeholders. While there are also [positional](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/update#positional) ones. Just question marks, you'll never confuse where to put a colon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a syntax error on this line

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET userName=:userName, name=:name, surName1:=surName1'.$strFields.' WHERE user_id=:user_id');
```

for surName1 you have the ":" on the wrong side of the equal sign.
Just change it to this

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET userName=:userName, name=:name, surName1=:surName1'.$strFields.' WHERE user_id=:user_id');
```